# How do you set desktop icon to large size in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, icons, desktop

How to set desktop icon on larg size from c++? Windows 7 professional is os & use dev c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by simulating the control key and mouse wheel combination. You can read more about this method in this article from The Code Project: 
[Programmatically resize Desktop icons to a small list in Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/deskicon.aspx)

> Resize the icons to be smaller. We
>   call this repeatedly until we get the
>   desired size: Collapse
>
> ```
> SendMessage( hWnd, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, MAKEWPARAM(MK_CONTROL, -WHEEL_DELTA), MAKELPARAM(0, 0) );
> ```
>
> Resize the icons to be bigger. We call
>   this repeatedly until we get the
>   desired size: Collapse
>
> ```
> SendMessage( hWnd, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, MAKEWPARAM(MK_CONTROL, WHEEL_DELTA), MAKELPARAM(0, 0) );
> ```

Alternatively you can edit the registry key for the desktop icon sizes:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"Shell Icon Size"="32"
```

The size mentions is in pixels, obviously :)

Comment: That sounds really hacky... isn't there a way to do it more cleanly?

Comment: Sure, just added the registry key method :P

Comment: @nico of course it's hacky. The user is meant to do this. You shouldn't be doing it behind their back.

Comment: An update for Win10 - the registry key now used is: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop  REG_DWORD  IconSize`
`IconSize` is, as expected, still measured in pixels (16-256).  You'll need to restart explorer.exe immediately after editing the registry.